# Taking an Implicit Derivative

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $y=(a^x)^y$

deriving according to $x$:

$y={e^{lna}}^{x+y}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}={e^{lna}}^{x+y}\cdot(\frac{x+y}{a}+(1+\frac{dy}{dx})lna)$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+y}{a}\cdot a^{x+y}+a^{x+y}lna+a^{x+y}lna\frac{dy}{dx}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}(1-a^{x+y}lna)=\frac{x+y}{a}a^{x+y}+a^{x+y}lna$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{a^{x+y}(\frac{x+y}{a}+lna)}{1-a^{x+y}lna}$

Is it correct? Do I must rise y to $e^{lny}$?

Answer (score 3):

we have $$y=(a^x)^y=a^{xy}$$ and taking the logarithm we get
$$\ln(y)=xy\ln(a)$$ and the derivative is given by
$$\frac{y'}{y}=y\ln(a)+xy'\ln(a)$$

Comment: so the answer is $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{ln(a)}{\frac{1}{y}-ln(a)x}$?